# How to solve slow performance, slow and long running CRONs in Magento Cloud?

Tags: magento2, cron, sql, performance, magento2-cloud

I'm having these two main issues below in my Magento 2.3.2 Enterprise Cloud.

- Heavy SQL load and site performance issues.
- Long-running and stuck CRON.

[image: New Relic Magento 2]

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

## Cause

Flat tables and indexers enabled.

## Solution

Starting with Magento 2.1.x and above, the use of a flat catalog is no longer a best practice and is not recommended. Continued use of this feature is known to cause performance degradation and other indexing issues. To disable the flat catalog:

1. In the Magento Admin, navigate to **Stores > Settings > Configuration**.
2. In the panel on the left under **Catalog**, choose **Catalog**.
3. Expand the **Storefront** section, and do the following:

   - Set Use **Flat Catalog Category** to No.
   - Set Use **Flat Catalog Product** to No.
4. When complete, click **Save Config**. Then when prompted, refresh the cache.
5. Flush cache by running `php bin/magento cache:flush`

If you can't change the **Use Flat Catalog Category** and **Use Flat Catalog Product** to No because the options are greyed out disable flat indexers in `app/etc/config.php`:

1. Run this command to make sure all indexers are set to Update by schedule: `php bin/magento indexer:set-mode schedule`
2. Edit app/etc/config.php and locate the lines with `flat_catalog_product` and `flat_catalog_category` - change them from 1 to 0 to disable them.
3. Run the command `php bin/magento app:config:import`
4. Run this command to confirm that the flat indexers are disabled: `php bin/magento indexer:status`
5. Flush cache by running `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Reference: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034631192